# Ajax success function and find parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On click I run a function that will do an ajax submission for each form that has the .red_active class. After the ajax submission or after the complete function I want to remove the parent's .red_active class. This is what I tried, can you help me spot my mistake?

```
 $('.edit_old').click(function(){
   $('.slider_edit').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('red_active')){
          $(this).find('.edit_form_slide').each(function(){
                    $(this).on('submit', function(e) {

                        e.preventDefault();
                        var data = $(this).serialize();
                        var url = $(this).attr('action');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log('submitted '+ url);
                                //$(this).parent().removeClass('.red_active');
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                console.log('fail');
                            }
                        });
                    });
              $(this).submit();
              //$(this).submit().parent().removeClass('.red_active');
          });
      }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because within the `success` handler the `this` keyword does not reference the `.edit_form_slide` as it does in the `each()` handler. You need to store the reference of `this` in a variable:

```
 $('.edit_old').click(function () {
     $('.slider_edit').each(function () {
         var $sliderEdit = $(this);
         if ($sliderEdit.hasClass('red_active')) {
             $sliderEdit.find('.edit_form_slide').each(function () {
                 var $editFormSlide = $(this); // store 'this' in a variable
                 $editFormSlide.on('submit', function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     var data = $editFormSlide.serialize();
                     var url = $editFormSlide.attr('action');
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: url,
                         data: data,
                         success: function (data) {
                             console.log('submitted ' + url);
                             $editFormSlide.parent().removeClass('.red_active');  // to use here, within the other scope
                         },
                         error: function () {
                             console.log('fail');
                         }
                     });
                 });
                 $editFormSlide.submit();
             });
         }
     });
 });
```

Note that I did the same for the `.slider_edit` selector too, just to keep things consistent. If you have nested `this` references it can get confusing to keep track of what is referencing what, without a named variable.

Answer (score 1):

First you can optimize and remove the `if` and `.find` lines

```
$('.slider_edit. red_active . edit_form_slide').each(function(){
```

has the same effect than :

```
$('.slider_edit').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('red_active')){
          $(this).find('.edit_form_slide').each(function(){
```

And next to find a parents with a class, the best way is to use `.parents()` and all beware of the `this` in your function, the `this` in the success function is not the this you are looking to. You should save the `$(this)` before the ajax call in a var and reuse it into `success` callback.

Full correction :

```
$('.edit_old').click(function() {
    $('.slider_edit.red_active .edit_form_slide').each(function() {
        var $formSlide = $(this);

        $formSlide.on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $formSlide.parents('.red_active:first').removeClass('.red_active');
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('fail');
                }
            });
        }).submit();
    });
});
```